# How to express Nothing else in the set?

Tags: alloy

[**Update**] I spent a lot of time studying @Hovercouch's fantastic solution (see his solution below). I took his solution, along with Peter Krien's insights and wrote up a summary: [3 ways to model the set of non-negative even numbers](http://xfront.com/Alloy/3-ways-to-model-the-set-of-non-negative-even-numbers.html). I welcome your comments.

I am trying to create an Alloy model that defines a set of integers. I want to constrain the set to the integers `0, 2, 4, ...`

I want to use a "generative" approach to defining the set:

1. `0` is in the set.
2. If `i` is in the set, then `i+2` is in the set.
3. Nothing else is in the set.

I am struggling with the last one - nothing else is in the set. How do I express that?

Below is the Alloy model that I created.

```
one sig PositiveEven {
     elements: set Int 
}

pred generate_set_members {
    0 in PositiveEven.elements
    all i: Int | i in PositiveEven.elements => i.plus[2] in PositiveEven.elements
    // Nothing else is in the set - How to express this?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to create a relationship that maps each number N to N+2, and then take the reflexive-transitive closure of that relationship over 0.

```
one sig PositiveEven {
     elements: set Int 
}

one sig Generator {
  rel: Int -> Int
} {
  all i: Int | i.rel = i.next.next
}

pred generate_set_members {
    PositiveEven.elements = 0.*(Generator.rel)
}

assert only_positive_elements {
  generate_set_members => 
    all i: Int | i in PositiveEven.elements <=> i >= 0 and i.rem[2] = 0
}
```

Note that you *cannot* use `i.plus[2]` instead of `i.next.next`, because Alloy integers overflow to negative.

Comment: Wow! This is terrific. Thank you @Hovercouch

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of this:

```
let iset[min,max,step] = { i : Int | 
      i>= min 
  and i<max 
  and i.minus[min].div[step].mul[step] 
      = i.minus[min] }

pred show[ s : set Int ] {
    iset[ 0, 10, 2 ] = s
}

run show for 0 but 8 int
```

The visualiser does not show the Int types so look in the Tree or Text view.

Comment: Hi @Peter Kriens, I didn't realize that a "let" expression can be used outside a predicate. Pretty neat! This is a remarkably clever solution! Thank you!

Comment: The let is a Alloy writer's dream come true. Just like recursion, enum, seq, en meta data. It is a shame this is not in Daniel's book. Then again, in this example a fun would also have worked. You did see the mail on the AlloyTools list? The macro function is described in http://alloytools.org/quickguide/macro.html

Comment: One more. I think it is not that much a clever solution as well as a very readable one. That is the goal I am chasing.